# How can I delete all (or any) discussions from my Disqus admin?

Tags: disqus

I put Disqus on my site. This created discussions and URLs in Disqus admin automatically.

However, then I saw I have some mistakes in the URLs. There are many discussions and I don't want to edit the URLs manually.

Is it possible to remove all the discussions, so as to create new ones? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to register a new shortname to get a completely clean slate. You can do this by uninstalling the plugin, then reinstalling. Then during configuration, select "Create new site" instead of choosing an existing one.